# Automatic generation of XSL-FO stylesheet

Tags: xsl-fo

Does Altova MapForce/ Stylevision or any free tool have support for XSL-FO stylesheet generation? I want to know if there is a way to generate a XSL-FO stylesheet using MapForce? I have a XML and I have the human readable visual PDF format I want it displayed as. Is there a way to map the xml data to the visual layout and auto-generate the XSL-FO stylesheet?  I can then test it multiple test XML documents I have with XmlSpy which has support for Apache FOP.

Answer (score 0):

Altova once offered AltovaXML, which was free and could do XML-> XSLFO processing. It seems to have been superseded with RaptorXML, which is no longer available in a free edition.